# bootstrap modal box inside modal box scroll issue css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used `bootstrap modal` for my web page to display modal box inside another modal box. I used the following code to close the opened model and open an another modal.

```
<script>
  function launch_modal(id) {
     // Hide all modals using class if required.
     $('.modal').modal('hide');
     $('#'+id).modal('show');
  }
</script>


<div class="modal fade" id="loginmodal"  role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body"> sample content
        <div class="text-right"><a href="javascript:void();" onClick="launch_modal('forgot-password-modal');">Forgot Password ?</a></div>
        <div class="modal-bottom"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

Everything works fine. But there is two scroll bars appeared on the right side of the window.

[image]

How to fix this or is there any other way to close opened model and open a new model inside a model box?

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle link.

Comment: Dont use a modalception, if you want 2 modals, hide the first, open the new and after doing the second modal stuff, open the first again.

Comment: I tried your solution. Still two scroll bar appears.

Comment: Without the ability to see your code I can't provide specific details. However, if you use Firebug or Web Inspector you should be able to determine which DIV is responsible for the scrollbar. If you designate "overflow:hidden" on that DIV it should eliminate the scrollbar. As long as the content in the inner modal is not larger than the outer you should be able to do this OK. I'm guessing the DIV in question is one within your first modal which contains the second modal when it is revealed.